# Dispatch action from redux store in non redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

For some days I've been wrapping my head around a problem and I just can't find a good solution.

Long story short, I just want a loader on screen every time I make a custom axios request. I have 6  basic requests instances with interceptors like:

```
export const axiosRequest1 = axios.create({
  //blabla
});

axiosRequest1.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
     check();
     return config;
  },
error => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosRequest1.interceptors.response.use(
  config => {
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I need to start a loader at first of this requests and get rid of it after the last one.

```
async function check() {
  if (checked === false) {
    checked = true;
    setTimeout(callback, 699);
  }
}
```

and the callback:

```
function callback() {
  isLoading = true;
  console.log('---------------');
  // and here i want to dispatch my actin from redux store with the value of isLoading.
```

The action looks like:

```
const setLoader = isLoading => dispatch => {
  return dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.SET_LOADER,
    isLoading: isLoading
  });
}
export default setLoader;
```

I would normally export my store and call the action creator, except the store declaration is like this.

```
const initStore = previousStore => {
  return createStore(//bla);};
```

So if I try that, a new store will pe created, which I don't want.

Does anyone have an idea about how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented this logic for handling global unauthorized requests, but I think you could use it for your case too. Just use axios global interceptors. Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

// Redux binders
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

// Our data store
import reduxStore from './store';

import App from './components/App';

const router = (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

import {didFireRequest, didFinishRequest} from './actions/global';
const {dispatch} = reduxStore;

/** Intercept outgoing requests and update loading indicator state. **/
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    dispatch(didFireRequest());
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    dispatch(didFinishRequest());
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

/** Intercept all responses update loading indicator state. **/
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    dispatch(didFinishRequest());
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    dispatch(didFinishRequest());
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


render(router, document.getElementById('app-root'));
```